# binning random data into groups of equal data point by their value

Tags: python

I got a 2-columns dataframe (volume and price), and I want to create 20 bins based on the volume column with equal amount of data in each bin.

I.e. if I got volume = [1,6,8,2,6,9,3,6] and 4 bins, I want to cut the data to 1st bin: 1:2, 2nd: 3:6, 3rd: 6:8, 4th: 8:9

then to find the average volume and price within each bin and plot a graph of volume(x-axis) against price(y-axis)

the intervals don't need to be equally spaced. I want to have the same number of data in each interval and determine the range of each interval, then find the average value of the data within each interval and plot it

```
data = df['Volume']

discrete_dat, cutoff = discretize(dat, 20)
myList = sorted(set(cutoff))
Cutoff = np.asarray(myList)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : fd['Volume'], 'Y' : df['dMidP']})  #we build a dataframe from the data
data_cut = pd.cut(data,Cutoff)            #we cut the data following the bins               #we cut the data following the bins     
grp = df_2.groupby(by = data_cut)        #we group the data by the cut
ret = grp.aggregate(np.mean)         #we produce an aggregate representation (mean) of each bin

plt.loglog(df['Volume'],df['dMidP'],'o')

plt.loglog(ret.X,ret.Y,'r-')
plt.title('Price Impact (Sell)')
plt.xlabel('Volume')
plt.ylabel('dMidP')

plt.show()
```

my raw data and output plot
[image]

[image]

however, when I use the counter function, it returns me the following, indicating the number of data points in each interval is different.

```
Counter({Interval(0.41299999999999998, 0.46400000000000002, closed='right'): 2029,
     Interval(0.877, 0.92800000000000005, closed='right'): 543,
     Interval(0.050999999999999997, 0.069599999999999995, closed='right'): 93,
     Interval(0.60299999999999998, 0.71399999999999997, closed='right'): 99,
     Interval(0.46400000000000002, 0.496, closed='right'): 93,
     Interval(0.092799999999999994, 0.125, closed='right'): 111,
     Interval(0.125, 0.14799999999999999, closed='right'): 86,
     Interval(0.0092800000000000001, 0.018599999999999998, closed='right'): 101,
     Interval(0.53800000000000003, 0.60299999999999998, closed='right'): 99,
     Interval(0.14799999999999999, 0.186, closed='right'): 108,
     Interval(0.018599999999999998, 0.023199999999999998, closed='right'): 102,
     Interval(0.186, 0.23200000000000001, closed='right'): 134,
     Interval(3.246, 4.2670000000000003, closed='right'): 85,
     Interval(0.496, 0.53800000000000003, closed='right'): 103,
     Interval(1.391, 1.716, closed='right'): 86,
     Interval(0.26400000000000001, 0.32500000000000001, closed='right'): 104,
     nan: 243,
     Interval(0.23200000000000001, 0.26400000000000001, closed='right'): 60,
     Interval(0.032500000000000001, 0.046399999999999997, closed='right'): 186,
     Interval(0.00464, 0.0092800000000000001, closed='right'): 87,
     Interval(0.023199999999999998, 0.032500000000000001, closed='right'): 74,
     Interval(0.71399999999999997, 0.877, closed='right'): 101,
     Interval(0.97399999999999998, 1.1359999999999999, closed='right'): 92,
     Interval(4.2670000000000003, 6.3120000000000003, closed='right'): 100,
     Interval(0.046399999999999997, 0.050999999999999997, closed='right'): 33,
     Interval(1.716, 1.855, closed='right'): 145,
     Interval(0.069599999999999995, 0.092799999999999994, closed='right'): 97,
     Interval(1.1359999999999999, 1.391, closed='right'): 319,
     Interval(2.319, 2.7829999999999999, closed='right'): 114,
     Interval(0.32500000000000001, 0.41299999999999998, closed='right'): 98,
     Interval(0.92800000000000005, 0.97399999999999998, closed='right'): 72,
     Interval(2.7829999999999999, 3.246, closed='right'): 75,
     Interval(2.1429999999999998, 2.319, closed='right'): 128,
     Interval(1.855, 2.1429999999999998, closed='right'): 56})
```

Comment: how is this different from yesterday's question? I am missing the subtlety, I think.

Comment: I think the one you answered is for sorted data instead of for random data, furthermore, it does not involve the plotting part (which I need to find the correspond y value as well)

Comment: Ok, thank you. You can use the bining procedure for random data as well, it is the same. For calculating a y value, and plotting, maybe you want to be more focussed on this question, so you get a useful answer.

Comment: thank you for your reply. actually instead of returning arrays of the grouped data, would it be possible to return the cut boundary instead? (e.g. array([  4.63768752e-03,   9.27537503e-03,   1.85507501e-02,
         2.31884376e-02,   3.24638126e-02,   4.63768752e-02,
         5.10145627e-02,   6.95653127e-02,   9.27537503e-02,
         1.25217563e-01,   1.48406001e-01,   1.85507501e-01,
         2.31884376e-01,   2.64348188e-01,   3.24638126e-01,
         4.12754189e-01,   4.63768752e-01,   4.96232564e-01,
         5.37971752e-01,   6.02899377e-01,   7.14203878e-01])